# Using Selenium and xpath to find the source link to an MP4 video on a web site e.g. Fmovies

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

selenium and xpath. I have a python script that uses selenium to scrape the video source from a movie website. I can get the script to play the video using Selenium but want to scrape the src link to the MP4 video file. I think my xpath syntax is incorrect.

```
**** Code ******
# Load selenium components
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\temp\\chromedriver.exe")

## Link to the movie as an example
url = "https://vw.ffmovies.sc/film/fatman-2020/watching/?server_id=3"
browser.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='player']")))
clickable = browser.find_element_by_id("player")
clickable.find_element_by_xpath('.//*').click()
browser.switch_to.frame("iframe-embed") 
time.sleep(5)

### This is where I am stuck.. It cannot find the xpath element.... 
##########################################################################################
## I am getting the xpath wrong. I want the video link to be stored in the link variable. 
link=browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="player"]/iframe').get_attribute('src')) 
## Getting error in the above code                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 

browser.close()
```

Any advice will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Add the html why you use iframe in the locator

Comment: show the html code for element that contains the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id='player'`
is outside the iframe so that you shouldn't use it in your xpath.

[image]

So you should consider the iframe as the root of your new context.

Instead of `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="player"]/iframe').get_attribute('src')` try:

`browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//video/source').get_attribute('src')`

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Appreciate the detailed answer so that I can improve my coding skills.

Comment: What kind of details do you expect?

Comment: I meant this is good for me to understand.. It had all the detailed steps. Thanks !!!